# How can we change the IP of Android emulator

Tags: android

I was trying to communicate with 2 PC emulators. But after that I found that ,both emulator has same IP. How can I distinguish between which IP is for which emulator? Is there a way to set different IPs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [interconnecting emulator instances](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#connecting) on the android developer pages

In short:

```
To allow one emulator instance to communicate with another, you must set up the necessary network redirections as illustrated below.

Assume that your environment is

    A is you development machine
    B is your first emulator instance, running on A
    C is your second emulator instance, running on A too

and you want to run a server on B, to which C will connect, here is how you could set it up:

    Set up the server on B, listening to 10.0.2.15:<serverPort>
    On B's console, set up a redirection from A:localhost:<localPort> to B:10.0.2.15:<serverPort>
    On C, have the client connect to 10.0.2.2:<localPort>

For example, if you wanted to run an HTTP server, you can select <serverPort> as 80 and <localPort> as 8080:

    B listens on 10.0.2.15:80
    On B's console, issue redir add tcp:8080:80
    C connects to 10.0.2.2:8080
```

Comment: Thanks KevinDTimm for your reply with great explanation. Since Im new to Android, can you say how can I redirect the IP . I'm doing like this..

Comment: Thanks KevinDTimm for your reply with great explanation. Since Im new to Android, can you say how can I use "redir add tcp:5000:80
" redirect the IP .I'm not aware about where i need to run this command. When i try this in console i'm getting <br/>The Vdm Redirector is already loaded.<br/> My code is like this..  <br/>

Comment: you say, on the console, does that mean telnet localhost 5554? also, is 80 already used for something else?  finally, include your additional questions in the original question, they're easier to read there :)